# CentOS 7 Apache run/execute web request as root user

Tags: browser, apache-http-server, php, sudo, centos-7

I have a PHP Utility which accepts post request with file as parameter. Now when that request is received I want to execute it as root user. For example when user hits www.mydomain.com/sendtextfiletoftp.php from postman or any other tool it should be executed as root user.

I have tired with `sudo visudo` and adding below lines to sudoers file, but still the request is executed with apache user

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/sendtextfiletoftp.php`

`apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/sendtextfiletoftp.php`

The same file when executed as sudo user from command line(`sudo php72 /path/to/file/sendtextfiletoftp.php`) works fine.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The web server doesn't actually execute those files; it reads them, and then the PHP module runs the code within.

Answer (score 0):

As well as allowing the apache user to become root for a command, you need to make a call within you code which includes 'sudo'. Typically:

In visudo I would put something like

apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/my_root_command

In my /var/www/html/sendtextfiletoftp.php code, for the specific part that needs root access, I would put something like:

exec("sudo /path/my_root_command");

Comment: Thank you EI_Tel,  What is my_root_command? I am using shell_exec(), will that do?

Comment: It could be shell script or system call. I haven't tried it but I suppose it could be a piece of php code

Comment: I have done this but does not work

Comment: I've had a proper look and this does work. I wrote a little shell script to tail /var/log/mesages which needs root or sudo access

Comment: $ cat /usr/local/bin/taillog.sh
#!/bin/bash
tail /var/log/messages

Comment: Then ran visudo and put in the line

apache ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/taillog.sh

My php script contained the line
 $log = system('/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/taillog.sh'); print $log;

It did not work at first since SELinux prevented it
Setting SELinux to Permissive allowed it to run.

Once it works ok then you can see what specific commands you need to configure SELinux to allow it to run when SELinux is enforcing